# Device showing 32-bit kernel instead of 64-kernel in boot.img

Tags: android, kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit, android-kernel

As the title said every device info or hardware info app I download from play store shows my device is 32-bit or the kernel is 32 bit but I extracted my kernel from the stock boot.img file and ran the command; file kernel and it shows

```
franklin@localhost /sdcard> file kernel

kernel: Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages

franklin@localhost /sdcard>.
```

My question is what makes my device 32 bit if the kernel is 64 bit.

And also I can not run scripts compiled for 64 bit Android devices.

I ran the command file kernel and it shows my kernel is 64 bit instead of 32 bit apps are reporting.

It shows

```
franklin@localhost /sdcard> file kernel

kernel: Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages

franklin@localhost /sdcard>
```

Instead of Linux kernel ARM boot executable Image the device info apps are reporting.

Comment: I would more trust the output of `uname -a` executed on your phone (e.g. via adb).